# can't reference a struct pointer to function unless it has been previously allocated (and freed)

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I supposed to write a long explanation of the code but the explanation is already in the code below so I guess my question is: How do I get it to work without having to malloc then freeing it? or basically what is the correct way to write this in a situation like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct d {
    int f;
};

struct d* rr() {
    struct d* p = malloc(sizeof (struct d*));
    p->f = 33;
    return p;
}

void rr2(struct d* p) {
    p = malloc(sizeof (struct d*));
    p->f = 22;
}



int main()
{
    //works..
    struct d* g;
    g = malloc(sizeof (struct d));
    g->f = 45;
    printf("[%i]", g->f);
    
    //works..
    g = rr();
    printf("[%i]", g->f);
    

    //below, both are same, except in this first case, g is allocated then freed..
 
    //works..
    free(g);
    rr2(g);
    printf("[%i]", g->f);
    
    //doesn't work..
    struct d *q;
    rr2(q);
    printf("[%i]", q->f);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `struct d gg; struct d *g = &gg;`

Comment: the root of the blatant memory leak in `rr2` is probably what is confusing you most; you just don't realize it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters in the both functions

```
struct d* rr() {
    struct d* p = malloc(sizeof (struct d*));
    p->f = 33;
    return p;
}
```

and

```
void rr2(struct d* p) {
    p = malloc(sizeof (struct d*));
    p->f = 22;
}
```

there is a typo. It seems you mean

```
    struct d* p = malloc(sizeof (struct d));
                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
    p = malloc(sizeof (struct d));
                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

or

```
    struct d* p = malloc(sizeof ( *p ));
                                 ^^^^^
```

and

```
    p = malloc(sizeof ( *p) );
                       ^^^^^
```

As for this function

```
void rr2(struct d* p) {
    p = malloc(sizeof (struct d*));
    p->f = 22;
}
```

then in this call

```
struct d *q;
rr2(q);
```

the pointer `q` is passed to the function by value. So the function deals with a copy of the pointer `q`. Changing the copy within the function does not reflect on the original pointer `q`. It stays unchanged.

To make the code working you have to pass the pointer by reference (indirectly through a pointer to it). In this case the function will look like

```
void rr2(struct d **p) {
    *p = malloc(sizeof (struct d ));
    ( *p )->f = 22;
}
```

and be called like

```
rr2( &q );
```

As for this code snippet

```
free(g);
rr2(g);
printf("[%i]", g->f);
```

then it just invokes undefined behavior because in this statement

```
printf("[%i]", g->f);
```

there is an access to already freed memory.